# My call_system function does not work with tokenized strings

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, token

I have written a function called call_system, which behaves similarly to system(); and uses execvp to execute the commands and their options. I am currently trying to allow there to be multiple programs run by separating the commands for example:

```
ls;echo test;cat;sort
```

When I hardcode values to send to my call_system function, it works fine, but when I tokenize an input string with ";" as the delimiter, it does not work. I have checked to see if the tokens are correct and they are.

The following is an extract of my code (it shows the relevant section in which I am trying to let call_system run multiple times):

```
//job list
const char s[2] = ";";
char *itoken;

/* get the first token */
itoken = strtok(str2, s);
//walk through other tokens 
while ( itoken != NULL){
        int i = 0;
    for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(itoken); i++){if (itoken[i] == '\n'){itoken[i] = '\0';}}

    //call_system(itoken);
    printf( "intoken: %s", itoken );
    itoken = strtok(NULL, s);
}

// call_system("ls");
// call_system("cat");
```

Run example:

```
ls;echo done;cat

pid of child = 4457
cat     hello     hello "world"   Makefile  test3
cat.c       hello2~   hello "world"~  README    test77
echooutput  hello2.c  hello world~    shell 
frtest      hello.c   input       shell.c
child 4457 exited with status = 0
intoken: ls
```

Comment: What is str2 variable ? Do you use commandline parameters to affect str2 ?

Comment: str2 is the original input text, eg. ls;cat;sort

Comment: well, if tokenization goes ok, then you should show us your call_system funtion. Otherwise I don't see how anybody can help you. Also what does it mean - does not work? Can you at least do `printf` debugging, to tell us where does the error occure?

Comment: hi, here is a link to all of the code, http://www.privatepaste.com/7b2a8f8106

Answer (score 0):

you make code so complex.
Not require to count command in string. `strtok` will extract command for you by delimiter `;` .

```
const char s[2] = ";";
char *itoken;
char str2[]="ls;echo test;cat file";

/* get the first token */
itoken = strtok(str2, s);


while ( itoken != NULL){

    call_system(itoken);
    itoken = strtok(NULL, s);

}
```

Also make some validation in code like after `fgtes`.

```
     while(1)
     {
       printf("STARTED AGAIN\n");
       fgets(str, 81, stdin);
       str[strlen(str) - 1] = '\0';

       if (str[0] != '\0') 
       {  
           //rest of code
        }
      }
```

Comment: Because I get another segfault if I do it that way

Comment: It does normally, but with everything else Im doing it somehow messes up

Comment: So tell me what is everything else  you do? And why you only execute `cat` and `sort` without any argument?

Comment: I mean `ls;echo test;cat;sort` you only give command name for `cat` and `sort` but not argument. can you take care of it in `call_system`? Can you show `call_system` function?

Comment: yeh once in call_system, I can continue to enter input, it uses execvp like i said

Comment: if you want to use the same compiler as me, i compile this with, "clang -Wall -std=c99 -o shell shell.c"

Comment: accidentally used the actual terminal, its actually still not working

Answer (score 0):

In your code try to replace char '\n' to '\0' just afer fgets function.

Like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(str) ; ++i)
    if (str[i] == '\n')
        str[i] = '\0';
```

Source: http://www.privatepaste.com/19ef5cf60f

Comment: Didn't help, thanks anyway. I already have something similar in my token while loop, "for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(itoken); i++){if (itoken[i] == '\n'){itoken[i] = '\0';}}"

Comment: But your string has no terminal character when it is used in strcmp function. If your buffer does not contain any '\0', strcmp func for example can not determine end of string.

Comment: accidentally used the actual terminal, its actually not working

Comment: Sorry but I didn't see any other errors in your code. Good luck !